# Reading sms without using GSM Modem?

Tags: sms, gsm, modem

I want to read sms in a mobile and process it in my server. I think it can be done with the help of GSM modem. But, i have been asked to do it without using GSM modem.Is there any other way to make it done?. If there is any other way, pls let me know.
(preferred languages to implement-java,c#/vb.net,php,c/c++)

*Update based on comment:*

I am planning to develop a SMS polling system using which our company employees can vote by sending SMS.

For example, the users will be asked to send sms in a particular format(say VOTE ) to a mobile number. I need to read the sms(which is in a mobile) from my server and it should be processed to calculate the result.

Comment: There are a few landlines which accept the SMS. For example, in India, we have a provider called Tata Indicom whose phones accept SMS. But how will you integrate your application with that device??

Comment: Please clarify your question. "I want to read sms in a mobile and process it in my server" does not make sense. Where does the SMS come from? How do you want to fetch it? You can't just grab it off a user's mobile phone...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am planning to develop a SMS polling system using which our company employees can vote by sending SMS.For example,the users will be asked to send sms in a particular format(say VOTE <option>) to a mobile number.I need to read the sms(which is in a mobile) from my server and it should be processed to calculate the result.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a gateway; like the one I mentioned in my post.

Comment: @urpalreloaded: If you have clarifications to your question, it's better to enter the question (not everyone reads all comments). I edited it for you :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a SMS Gateway. There are plenty of services out there; like For example this service http://clickatell.com/products/gateway.php

They usually provide an API that you can use to integrate it with your servers.

You have some basic information on SMS Gateways available on Wikipedia here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway

And a list of SMS Gateways available here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways